# django tutorial returns 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'

Tags: django, ubuntu-10.04

I'm following the django tutorial: version 1.8, Ubuntu 10.04, python 3.4 in a virtual environment.  I seem to create a django project (yatest) on my Ubuntu server just fine and I start the development server:

```
(v1)cj@drop1:~/www/yatest$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 09, 2015 - 04:37:33
Django version 1.8.3, using settings 'yatest.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

but when I browse to http://myserver:8000 all I get in response is 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'.

This is the first part of the tutorial before an app is even created. At this early stage in the tutorial it doesn't mention any error log I can check.  My telnet client doesn't say anything crashed, and 'ctl-c' will shutdown the server process with no complaints.

Using netstat -lntp I verified no other processes are using port 8000.  I do not have Apache installed.  I do have gunicorn and nginx installed but both are stopped and not in use yet in the tutorial.

I'm rather new to linux; I could use some help finding an error log or other debugging tools to solve this.  I don't doubt I've missed some basic OS setting or something to enable TCP access, etc..

Thanks
Clark

Comment: Can you link the tutorial you are following?

Comment: Where are you accessing it from? The same machine, or a different one? And what happens if you use 127.0.0.1 as described in the tutorial?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Different machine.  Other tutorials imply it should be accessible from outside even at this early stage, but if that's not the case, please let me know.

Comment: @aa333 Tutorial is here: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/.   I'm at the part just after creating the django project.

Answer (score 14):

Found my mistake.  When starting a dev django server on dedicated server one MUST include the dedicated server's address in the command.  This is not needed when launching a dev server on the same machine as your browser. So instead of

```
$python manage.py runserver
```

you have to run 
`$python manage.py runserver <server ip>:8000`.

So this is my inglorious start on stack exchange.  You saw nothing! :P

Comment: I had the same issue running Django inside a container via docker! You saved my life

Answer (score 10):

If you're running natively in an virtual envrionment, then you need to specify a port and address:

`python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`

For containers, it's easiest to listen to all addresses:

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

For anybody using PyCharm in a docker environment, it's also worth knowing that PyCharm will override your `docker-compose` configuration to change the `runserver` command to bind to the port specified in the `Host` option in your `Run/Debug Configurations` window.

Make sure you set the Host to `0.0.0.0` and the port to `8000` if you want to use the debugger etc.

Comment: Agree with the Pycharm comment. You can't have a custom port and host for running Django. It makes absolutely no sense at all. Why does the host have to be "0.0.0.0" and the port "8000"?

Comment: I was using django in a docker container on my macbook and adding the `0.0.0.0:8000` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the trouble to determine server ip (ie when you're using containers), you can listen to 0.0.0.0:8000

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```